# Satellite and gravitational acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile, geometry, calculus

According to $0.5gt^2$ object will fall 5m in first second.

Earth curve is 5m for 8km
[image]

So if we can project object at 8000 m/s speed object will never fall into ground.

Above scenario is correct for first second. what about 2nd second.
according to $0.5gt^2$ object will fall 20m for t =2.

Now horizontal V = 8000 m/s 
Earth curve = 5m per 8km

Now object should hit the ground.

Someone can explain this to me.

Comment: The Earth doesn't "drop" with a linear function of distance but quadratically. Even your drawing shows that.

Comment: @Mapalagama: Welcome to physics.stackexchange.com. Very interesting question. Mathematical explanation will be simple, but a good way to put it. I will just put a descriptive explanation.

The direction of fall is continuously changing, so the formula I guess does not really apply for the whole time, it only applies for an instant and then the direction is changed. If the centripital force is same or more than the weight of the body, then it will not hit ground (ignoring hurdles/resistances), otherwise, it will fall.

Comment: Also, it matters if the given velocities are just initial velocities or constant velocities for the whole periods of considerations. But I would like to assume that the latter is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's calculate that "drop" of Earth's surface:

$8km$ from launch: $6.5\times 10^6m-\sqrt{(6.5\times10^6m)^2-(8000m)^2}\approx4.9m$

$16km$ from launch: $6.5\times 10^6m-\sqrt{(6.5\times 10^6m)^2-(2*8000m)^2}\approx19.7m$.

It's not a problem, not even in the straight fall approximation, but you have to calculate the position of Earth's surface correctly. There is a very simple physical explanation for this: the planet is spherical because its volume elements "drop" just as a freely falling body would. The mechanical strength of the matter the planet is made of is not sufficient to withstand most of the gravitational force. At most it can push parts of its surface "up" by something like 20km before gravity "wins".

Comment: which formula is used to calculate drop of earth

Comment: @Mapalagama: I approximate it with a circle along the plane of the trajectory, i.e. $x^2+y^2=r^2$. That's the correct way of doing it. To pretend that the planet is an inclined plane towards the horizon is simply false.